# Entity Framework querying error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Why does this work:

```
List<Item> items = ndb.Items.Where(m => m.ProductId == id).OrderByDescending(m => m.Id).ToList();
int itemid = items[0].Id;
bool wlexists = ndb.Wishlists.Any(m => m.ItemId == itemid && m.UserEmail == User.Identity.Name);
```

And this doesn't :

```
List<Item> items = ndb.Items.Where(m => m.ProductId == id).OrderByDescending(m => m.Id).ToList();

bool wlexists = ndb.Wishlists.Any(m => m.ItemId == items[0].Id && m.UserEmail == User.Identity.Name);
```

Comment: I see no reason why the second query won't work, what is exception you get ?

Answer (score 0):

It must work if the `items` had value i.e not null . What error you are getting???

Do like this.

```cs
 List<Item> items = ndb.Items.Where(m => m.ProductId == id).OrderByDescending(m => m.Id).ToList();
 if(items!=null)
 bool wlexists = ndb.Wishlists.Any(m => m.ItemId == items[0].Id && m.UserEmail == User.Identity.Name);
```